# JavaScript function explanation for Blackjack game

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this blackjack problem on learnstreet:

http://www.learnstreet.com/cg/simple/project/blackjack#get-hint

I am stuck on the last method getStrategy() - here's a description of how the task is to be completed:

"This method simulates the dealer's strategy, so that he knows when to hit and when to stand -- i.e., when to accept another draw from the deck and risk "going bust" and breaking 21, or stopping with the current hand and hoping his opponent will not beat his number.

This is a special function in that it returns an object that is a function itself. (How's that for crazy?) It accepts 'n', an integer score of the dealer's hand at which point the dealer's strategy is to hit or to stand. (Blackjack dealers usually take hits when his cards total less than 17 points, so n would be 17 in that case.)

What you need to return in this method should be in the form of "return function(currenthand){};" where you fill in what's inside the curly braces ({}). The current hand will be supplied to the function call, and you will need to write some logic where the dealer compares the current hand's points with 'n'."

LearnStreet implemented getSrategt() in this way:

```
function getstrategy(n) {
    return function(currenthand) {
        return (countpoints(currenthand) < n);
    }
}
```

The getStrategy() method is called in the applyStrategy method like this:

```
/*
This function applies the strategy you define in getstrategy(n): DON'T CHANGE
*/
function applystrategy(hand, n) {
    var strat = getstrategy(n);
    return strat(hand); 
}
```

Can anybody please explain to me why we are returning (countpoints(currenthand) < n)?

Comment: @AlienArrays It's not two returns in one function. `getstrategy` is returning an anonymous function that returns the comparison of `countpoints(currenthand) < n)` which is a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

`countpoints(currenthand)` will return the number of points in the hand. `n` is `17`, the number where, if the current points is less than, the dealer will take another hit. Basically, if current points is less than `17`, keep playing, if it is equal to or greater, stop.